# VB .NET - TryParseExact finally working but giving unexpected results [RESOLVED - Dumb mistake]

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I've got a program which pulls some data from a couple of web pages, and unfortunately the date format changes from Little-Endian to Big-Endian at some point.  I'm a Big-Endian kinda guy, so everything is converted to that format later in the code.

I'm ditching my custom functions for built-ins to do this, and ended up with something which finally compiled:

```
Dim dateString As String = "2020-03-02"   'Note #1
Dim result As DateTime
If Date.TryParseExact(parts(1), "yyyy-mm-dd", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, result) Then 'Note #2
   myDate = result
End If
```

In pause, I see the result as: "#1/2/2020 12:03:00AM#"

Note #1: This was actually an element of an array of string.split()

Note #2: If this TryParseExact failed, I was going to test against "dd-mm-yyyy" after

I've been playing with this for about 2 weeks, and finally need some expert help.
Where am I going wrong please, and as a bonus code correction, if you could also provide the same for a dd-mm-yyyy test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lower case "m" is for minutes in date/time formatting strings. Upper case "M" is for months. The relevant documentation:

[Custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Comment: Thanks.  I had actually read the documentation, it was a simple mistake I didn't spot until about 5 seconds after posting, and then StackOverflow went down for maintenance.  I've been trying to remove the question for about 30 mins.

I appreciate the swift response, although the sarcasm wasn't. (probably deserved though).